# Unable to open sqlite3 database file

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlite

'm using sqlite3 with eclipse.
This is the first time i'm using this and when i try creating the database this is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\New wrokspace\books\books\manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 286, in handle
    app_output = self.handle_app(app, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\sqlall.py", line 19, in handle_app
    return u'\n'.join(sql_all(app, self.style, connections[options.get('database', DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS)])).encode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 146, in sql_all
    return sql_create(app, style, connection) + sql_custom(app, style, connection) + sql_indexes(app, style, connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 26, in sql_create
    tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 791, in table_names
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 207, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
Finished "F:\New wrokspace\books\books\manage.py sqlall books" execution.
```

Can someone tell me how to create and open sqlite3 databases on eclipse??

Thanks

Comment: Have you do a `syncdb` first? Does your DB file exists?

Answer (score 0):

To create the database with Django, you have to write your models, put applications in the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` and then:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

The [sqlall](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname) command prints the CREATE TABLE and initial-data SQL statements for the given app name(s).

Comment: Yeah. Its in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS
N when i ran the syncdb command , it gives me the same error.

Comment: Check folder permission..